# Move an image across the page a random amount

Tags: javascript, image, random, move

I am trying to move an image across the page using a random number that will affect how much the image will move. I got the random number to display so I know the number is generating but my image won't move at all.

Below is the html, javascript, and css that I have used:

http://jsbin.com/bodajisihu/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Please share your code in the question directly and not as a link. Questions must be valid for further reference from other users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsbin.com/begafabuya/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Please check this edited JSBin.

I made following changes:
 1. You were trying to get `left` value as `car1.style.left`, which doesn't work for an image if you have defined `left` in external style. You needed to make it inline.
 2. Now, you can use `car1.style.left`, but still it returns a string with 'px' appended to it, so I replaced that using `.replace("px", "")`. But I think `parseInt` alone could take care of truncating that bit, so this point may not matter

Please note here that car1 is reference to the car element i.e. `var car1 = document.getElementById('car1');`.

Comment: Please share what have you done. Questions and answers should be for reference for future users who may face the same issue

Comment: @Mike Thank you! My problem was defining the style in an external CSS. Once I defined the left style in the img tag, my problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

You misspelled the function name. There's an "s" in "moveCars"

Comment: That was just a typo. I fixed that and it still doesn't work.